# Confirm exit before destroying component in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to utilize one of the angular's life-cycle callback hooks, `ngOnDestroy` to prevent Angular from destroying my component by observing an interesting state of the an App occurs, e.g. when user has unsaved changes. As it is a custom to ask users if they are certain of their actions using a dialog, my current implementation looks as follows:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'admin-edit-product-form'
   // ...
})
export class AdminEditProductFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   // here goes my form
   productForm: FormGroup;
   // ...
   constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder,
      private mDiagService: ModalDialogService) {}      

   ngInit() {
      // initialize fb
      productForm = fb.group(/*initialization*/)
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
       // HOW DO I BLOCK Angular at this stage in a Subscriber?
       if (this.productForm.dirty) {
         this.mDialogService.confirm({
           title: 'You have unsaved changes',
           content: 'Any unsaved changes will be permenently lost. Sure you want to exit?',
           btnOkText: 'Exit',
           btnCancelText: 'Remain'
        }).subscribe(confirmed => {
           if (!confirmed) {
              // HOW DO I DO IT HERE?
           }
        })
      }
   }
}
```

That may not be the only way of doing it. If there is any suggestion. Please, I'm looking forward to it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a CanDeactivate guard in your router.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17404